# Performance Improvement on spring mail

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, email, gmail

I have to send an mail whenever an order is placed. I am using a spring boot application. I am using spring-boot-starter-mail. I am using gmail-smtp.

Problem: It takes 13 seconds to send a single email. It is a sooo costly operation.

Exception:

I want some performance optimization and and also I want to understand how e-commerce companies will send an email so quickly as soon as an order is placed.

```
public class SendEmailImpl implements SendEmail {

@Autowired
private JavaMailSender mailSender;

@Override
public String Sendmail(Sender sender) {
    SimpleMailMessage smm = new SimpleMailMessage();
    smm.setTo(sender.getDestinationEmail());
    smm.setFrom(sender.getSourceEmail());
    smm.setSubject(sender.getSubject());
    smm.setText(sender.getDescription());

    mailSender.send(smm);
    
    return "The Message send successfully";
}
```

Config:

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout = 5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout = 5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout = 5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable = true
spring.mail.host = smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port = 587
spring.mail.username =
spring.mail.password =
```

Comment: E-commerce companies have their own email servers. The reason could be they don’t need to hop through different security channels.

Comment: Is there anyway for me to optimise it

Comment: Is it faster if you are connecting to a different E-Mail server (maybe in your local network)? I think the main problem is not the code but the connection to the E-Mail server.